# PHP how to quote string array values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

If I have the following array `$array[0] = array(
    "1" => bar,
    "2" => foo,
    "3" => 13546
);` and I implode() it, the value that is returned will be: `bar,foo,13546` which cannot be used in a mysql query... How can I place single quotes just to those values that are strings...

I've tryed a couple of ways (like `foreach($array as $key=>$value)` to check with is_numeric() the $value, and the check is ok but I dont know how to change the value to '$value'...)

Any toughts on this?

**EDIT**

I found another way to do this for those of you who are interested:

```
$result[0] = array(
    "1" => bar,
    "2" => foo,
    "3" => 1232.13
);

$copy_r = $result[0];

foreach($copy_r as $key=>$value)
{
    if(!is_numeric($value))
    {
        $insert_array[] = "`$key` = '$value'";
    }
    else
    {
        $insert_array[] = "`$key` = $value";
    }
}

$final_string = implode(',', $insert_array);
$insert_q = "INSERT INTO `table_name` SET $final_string
             ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ($final_string)";
```

Comment: That's not how you want to do this. You should be using prepared queries.

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: Google can, `prepared statements`

Comment: take a look at http://uk1.php.net/pdo and prepared statements.

Comment: also see here: http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: binding parameter... does it work on mysqli? or mysql? I dont have the PDO class installed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better use prepared queries. But just for funs sake:

```
implode(',', array_map(function($value) {
    if(!is_numeric($value)) {
        return '"' . $value . '"';
        //adds double quotes, but if you prefer single quotes, use:
        //return "'" . $value . "'";
    } else {
        return $value;
    }
}, $array[0]);
```

Answer (score 8):

Agree that you should look at prepared statements, however to answer your original question you can do that like this:

```
$array=array('a', 'b', 'c');

$string = "'" . implode("','", $array) . "'";
```

Comment: He wants to surround only string values with `'`, numeric values are supposed to remain blank.

Answer (score 0):

The foreach+isnumeric() is probably the best approach. Then to change the value:

```
$array[$key] = "'" . $value . "'";
```

which turns `foo/"foo"` into `'foo'/"'foo'"` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the mysql-driver:

```
function escape( $x ) {
 return "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($x) . "'";
}

$data = array( "1" => bar, "2" => foo, "3" => 13546 );

echo implode( ',', array_map('escape', $data) );
```

Answer (score -1):

The verified solution didn't work for me. Must be something that i'm doing incorrectly, but the below solution worked for me and i used the result in my MYSQL `IN` clause since all the values needs to be in quoted form in that query.

The solution is simple and it uses call by reference to modify the original array values and array filter of PHP to loop through all the values.

```
function quote(&$a){
      $a='"'.$a.'"';
    }

    $arr= array('car','bus','truck','bike');

    array_filter( $arr,'quote');

    echo implode(',', $arr);
```

Comment: You should use prepared statements as this just keeps open the SQL injection vulnerability. Also, this quotes everything, which was not what the OP asked. Finally, using `array_filter` to mutate an array is bad practice.

Comment: Questions:
1. I am just creating a string here and storing it in variable that i can use in my php code like IN ($arr), so how will this keep the system vulnerable?

Comment: and should i use array_map() for  this purpose?

Comment: I will not explain SQL injection here. Just one example: when `$arr` contains a value like `') or 1=1 or 'x' in ('`, then the SQL statement will not have the desired effect. (2) you should use `array_map` and not mutate the array in the function, but *return* the modified values, and use the return value of `array_map`.