# PHP/AJAX QUERYBUILDER -> Encapsulating Array Data in Quotes for Textual Update

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to update my database using querybuilder, however it is only allowing numeric updates, not textual updates to the varchar fields in my database.  From researching I understand this is because I need to encapsulate my data in single quotes  (From StackOverflow Reference: "[PHP how to quote string array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529383/php-how-to-quote-string-array-values)")

I am having trouble figuring out how to encapsulate my "item" data from the array being passed to querybuilder for the update.  (Inserts work just fine text or numeric.  However updates only take the numeric entries.)

Here is my data:

```
 {"items":[{"agentID":"26","agentCompanyID":"11","agentName":"a","agentEmail":"b","agentPhone":"c"},{"agentID":"27","agentCompanyID":"11","agentName":"c1","agentEmail":"c2","agentPhone":"c3"},{"agentID":"25","agentCompanyID":"11","agentName":"41","agentEmail":"41","agentPhone":"41"},{"agentID":"24","agentCompanyID":"11","agentName":"41","agentEmail":"41","agentPhone":"41"}]}
```

Here is my code for the processing php file to querybuilder, any advice on how to do this would be appreciated, as I have tried a few different ways but have been unable to figure it out.

```
case "addAgent":
{
  $data = urldecode($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = json_decode($data, true);

      if(count($data[items])!=0)
      {
      $irVal = 0;
      $tempAgentId = 0;

          foreach($data[items] as $key=>$value)
          {
          $tempAgentId = $data['items']['$irVal']['agentID'];

             if ($tempAgentId == '0')
             {
             $iq = new InsertQuery("auth_agents");
             $iq->addItem('agentCompanyID',filter_var($value['agentCompanyID'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
             $iq->addItem('agentName',filter_var($value['agentName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
             $iq->addItem('agentPhone',filter_var($value['agentPhone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
             $iq->addItem('agentEmail',filter_var($value['agentEmail'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

             $query = $iq->generateQuery();
             error_reporting(1);
             $bool = TableFunctions::executeQuery($query);
             echo $query;
             }
             else // is an update
             {
             $uq = new UpdateQuery("auth_agents");
             $uq->addItem('agentCompanyID',filter_var($value['agentCompanyID'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
             $uq->addItem('agentName',filter_var($value['agentName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
             $uq->addItem('agentPhone',filter_var($value['agentPhone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
             $uq->addItem('agentEmail',filter_var($value['agentEmail'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

             $uq->addCondition("agentID",$value['agentID']);
             $query = $uq->generateQuery();
             error_reporting(1);
             $bool = TableFunctions::executeQuery($query);
             echo $query;
             }

       $tempAgentId = 0;
       $irVal++;
    }
   }
   break;
  }
 }
```

--> My query runs and loops through the array items to perform the insert or update for each item.  And inserts work just fine for text or numeric, but updates will only allow numeric.  I need to be able to pass text in the updates.  Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Well I must have just been looking at this too long and was overlooking the obvious.  Here is how I fixed the issue with the updates:

Changed the $uq->addItem values to include the single quotes for me as follows.

```
 $uq->addItem('agentCompanyID',"'".$value[agentCompanyID]."'");
    $uq->addItem('agentName',"'".$value[agentName]."'");
    $uq->addItem('agentPhone',"'".$value[agentPhone]."'");
    $uq->addItem('agentEmail',"'".$value[agentEmail]."'");
```

Worked like a charm.  Appreciate all who viewed.  Good luck out there!!